# Issues with template class conversion - unable to deduce function called

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, implicit-conversion, template-argument-deduction

How do I make the following code work properly?

The non-template version compiles perfectly but the template version fails miserably. Why template version fails to figure out which function version to call and how to fix it? I thought about adding to template class AT operator that implicitly converts to BT but it doesn't work either.

```
class A {};

class B
{
    public: 
    B(A){};
};

void func(B){};

template<typename T>
class AT {};

template<typename T>
class BT
{
    public: 
    BT(AT<T>){};
};

template<typename T>
void funcT(BT<T>){};

int main()
{
    func(A{});
    funcT(AT<int>{}); // unable to deduce the funcT template argument
    funcT<int>(AT<int>{}); // compiles but I don't want to write that

    return 0;
}
```

There are dumb fixes like writing function version that accepts `AT<T>` and casts it to `BT<T>`. But I don't want to write a bunch of functions when everything should work as is. I could understand it if it was an ambiguous call...

Comment: Whereas in your current case `AT<int>` can only construct `BT<int>`, but in general case, it is more complicated (And think about specializing `BT<char>` to take `AT<int>` as constructor, or add `CT` deriving from `BT<T>` declaring its own constructor).

Comment: Another [work around](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1e11ab13e73e5a68) to have only one `funcT`.

Answer (score 2):

Implicit conversion won't be considered in [template argument deduction](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_argument_deduction#Implicit_conversions):

> Type deduction does not consider implicit conversions (other than type adjustments listed above): that's the job for [overload resolution](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/overload_resolution), which happens later.

That means, for `funcT` which expects a `BT<T>` but passed a `AT<int>`, `T` can't be deduced and the fails to be called.

The workaround, as you showed, is to specify template argument explicitly to bypass the template argument deduction.

Non-template functions don't have such issue; they don't require template argument deduction.

Answer (score 0):

The other answer explained what was going on, but there is a way around this

```
template<class T, template<class>class Temp, typename std::enable_if<std::is_convertible< Temp<T>, BT<T>>::value, bool>::type = true>
void funcT(Temp<T> t) { 
    auto bt = static_cast<BT<T>>(t);
}
```

This can be called by `fooT(A<int>{});` as well as `fooT(B<int>{});` having the same behavior.

Comment: OP already suggested `template<typename T>
void funcT(AT<T> a){ funcT(BT<T>{a}); }`

Comment: Yes, and their problem was to write "a bunch of functions". This is one function for an arbitrary number of templates convertible to `BT`.